# W3C validation error on script "auto&null"

Tags: w3c-validation

I have this part of script in my website:

`this.isAuto=!1!==this.o.auto&null!==this.o.autoMode.match(/^loop|bounce$j/); w3 validation`

I am getting validation error at `auto&null`, `n` is red

here is the message:

> Warning Line 205, Column 409: cannot generate system identifier for
>   general entity "null"
>
> …h,b||{});this.isAuto=!1!==this.o.auto&null!==this.o.autoMode.match(/^loop|boun…
>
> ✉
>
> An entity reference was found in the document, but there is no
>   reference by that name defined. Often this is caused by misspelling
>   the reference name, unencoded ampersands, or by leaving off the
>   trailing semicolon (;). The most common cause of this error is
>   unencoded ampersands in URLs as described by the WDG in "Ampersands in
>   URLs".
>
> Entity references start with an ampersand (&) and end with a semicolon
>   (;). If you want to use a literal ampersand in your document you must
>   encode it as "&" (even inside URLs!). Be careful to end entity
>   references with a semicolon or your entity reference may get
>   interpreted in connection with the following text. Also keep in mind
>   that named entity references are case-sensitive; &Aelig; and æ
>   are different characters.
>
> If this error appears in some markup generated by PHP's session
>   handling code, this article has explanations and solutions to your
>   problem.
>
> Note that in most documents, errors related to entity references will
>   trigger up to 5 separate messages from the Validator. Usually these
>   will all disappear when the original problem is fixed.

I hope some one can help with that

Thanks

Comment: You're validating Javascript with the HTML validator?

Comment: Thanks Carpetsmoker, How I can avoid that error, or do I have to ignore this error, and where to find java script validator? thank you

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your html... Perhaps you need to add [`<![CDATA[`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)?